# PC installer desktop shortcut and uninstall confirmation

Tags: localization, installation, nsis

Currently working with NSIS to create an installer for my PC game, was wondering if there is a way (some default command) to be able to do the 2 following things :

1. Prompt the user for confirmation when he uninstalls the game (I am currently doing it manually (AKA messagebox) but my problem is that it's always in English (I pretty much want the message to be localized, am wondering if there is a default option to prompt the user that would be localized by default, like the rest of the installer).
2. Ask to create desktop shortcut (again, I am doing this using the MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT, but my text isn't localised)

If there are no default ways of doing this what would be the best way to go to be able to localise those two sentences in my installer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a uninstall confirm page you can use:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
...
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

You can localize strings by using `LangString`s:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT "$(FinishDeskLnkCheck)"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_FUNCTION CreateDeskLnk
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE Swedish

LangString FinishDeskLnkCheck ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Create Desktop shortcut?"
LangString FinishDeskLnkCheck ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Bork Desktop bork bork?"

Function .onInit
!define MUI_LANGDLL_ALWAYSSHOW
!define MUI_LANGDLL_ALLLANGUAGES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY
FunctionEnd

; NOTE: Uninstaller langstring names must be prefixed with "un."
LangString ConfirmUninstMsg ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Kill it?"
LangString ConfirmUninstMsg ${LANG_SWEDISH} "Bork it?"
Function TranslateMsgBoxExample
MessageBox MB_YESNO "$(ConfirmUninstMsg)"
FunctionEnd

Function CreateDeskLnk
; CreateShortcut ...
Call TranslateMsgBoxExample
FunctionEnd
```

The text on the buttons in a MessageBox is going to use the current users UI language and cannot be translated...

Comment: Works like a charm. @Anders Is it normal that the uninstaller message language defaults to the system language, or should it display the same language as the one chosen during installation ?

Comment: You can display the language selection dialog in the uninstaller as well (in un.onInit) or you can save $Language in the installer and restore this value in the uninstaller...